# Custom table view cell selection font color

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. It has 3 custom labels inside it with custom text.

When i tap on the cell, i want the textColor of all those labels to go white. just like Email app `UITableViewCell` behavior.

For that, I wrote this in the custom cell class.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    if (self.selected) {
        _subjectLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _usernameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }else {
        _subjectLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        _usernameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }



}
```

I was able to get it. But its not as smooth as it is in the Email app. The color changes only after a small delay. Which method of `UITableViewCell` should I override to put this code in. I know about the below options, but they don't give the behavior onto custom labels in the custom cell.

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray
} UITableViewCellSelectionStyle;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the label's highlightedTextColor and this will all be done for you automatically. You should not have to do anything special in **setSelected** at all.

e.g.

```
_subjectLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Just a small reminder, if the cell is a custom one, you can open the xib and under the Attributes Inspector, you can set "Highlighted" color.

Answer (score 1):

When we select any cell of `UITableView` , `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method called immediately, you can use this.

Comment: `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` fires only when you take your finger out of the cell.. not when you are keeping on it.. i want the color to change the moment when i keep the finger on the cell.. look email app for example

Comment: In that case you can use touchBegan method, as soon as you put your finger over cell this will be called, currently which method you are using?

Comment: which method you are using for calling this?

Comment: in the navigation controller, when the user comes back to the table, the blue should fade out and the labels text should go to black again...

Comment: the cell calls this `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method

Comment: what i am getting from your question what you want is - when you touch cell then it will change color, is this correct?

Comment: the custom labels inside the cell should change their font color to white when the cell is in selected state or else they all should go black when the cell is not in selected state.